# How to Correctly Wire This Outdoor Light/3-way Switches Setup?

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image: 3-Way wiring mock-up]

The picture is a mock-up of the wiring I found in my home when trying to get an exterior light working. None of these are the actual devices. I just used them to try to wrap my mind around what was going on. Also, the grounds were all connected – I just left them all out of the model for simplicity

The wire tagged in red represents the line coming in. There is no problem wiring it to a switch for the outside light represented by the wires tagged with blue. So that can be taken out of the equation.

The 3-way switch on the left is wired as I found it with the white wire connected to the common and the red and black wires acting as travelers (I think).

The wires tagged in yellow go to the light fixture. I have verified that connecting the line directly to the light fixture works.

My question is how to wire the 3-way switches in a way that they will function as desired.

Here is my best guess as an amateur...

- The neutral coming into the box would be connected to the neutral of the light fixture
- The common from switch 1 would go to the light fixture
- The line would be connected to the white 3-way wire, making it the
  line going to switch 2
- The black and red wires would act as the travelers between switches
  1 and 2

Am I getting this right?

(Please note, this isn’t how I would do it if I were starting from scratch. I just want to return it to functioning the way it did 2 days ago. I’m expecting a big renovation in this half of the house in the next 2 years or so. At that time a major overhaul of the electrical system will happen. I just want to be safe and well-lit for now.)

Comment: Basically correct. The white wire running to the three way should be taped/marked red or black at each end (or any other hot color, I prefer red as it's obviously not "random tape") to indicate that it is Not A Neutral. This is perfectly normal Pre-NEC 2011 US-type switch wiring.